# How Can I Select Multiple Text Boxes? (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

In VBA for Microsoft Word, I am trying writing a subroutine that will search through all shapes on a document, find the ones that are textboxes, and will move them to a newly created document by means of cut-and-paste.

My problem is that the sub will only move the first textbox it finds to a new doc. If I run it again it will move the next one, etc. Is there a way that I can select multiple textboxes, similar to the Shift-Left_Click ability that exists in the normal word document? I will post my code below:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public shp As Shape
    Public Count As Integer
    Public OldDoc As String
    Public NewDoc As String

    Sub BringTextBoxesToDoc()
        Dim Count As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Count = 0

        OldDoc = ActiveDocument.Name
        Documents.Add
        ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption = "Comment Textboxes"
        NewDoc = ActiveDocument.Name
        Documents(OldDoc).Activate

        For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
                Count = Count + 1
                shp.Name = "Textbox" & Count

                shp.Select
                With Selection
                    .Cut
                End With

                Documents(NewDoc).Activate
                Selection.Paste
            End If
        Next shp
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's cause youre making the paste document the active one, you need to reference the sending doc in the loop construction, so `for each shp in thisDocument.Shapes`

Comment: When I changed it to "thisDocument.Shapes" it does not copy any textbox. I understand that the problem is that I activate a new textbox, but I do not see any other way to loop it.

Comment: you need to do something like this before the loop, `dim docCopyFrom as word.document:set docCopyFrom=ActiveDocument:for each shp in docCopyFrom.Shapes`

Comment: This also does not copy any text. Should I perhaps try to make another loop using the "Count" variable to copy text?